Unable to get Plotly Data of type Figure using Langchain SQL Agent
I'm getting summary answer in response but want Plotly Data.
I tried using langchain sql agent to get response. But I'm getting summarized answer instead of Plotly Data.
from langchain.sql_database import SQLDatabase
from langchain.agents import create_sql_agent,AgentType
from langchain.agents.agent_toolkits import SQLDatabaseToolkit
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from langchain_openai import AzureChatOpenAI

load_dotenv()

sqlalchemy_url = f'sqlalchemy_url'
api_key ="api_key"
db = SQLDatabase.from_uri(sqlalchemy_url)
llm = AzureChatOpenAI(
                azure_endpoint="azure_endpoint",
                api_key=api_key,
                deployment_name="deployment_name",
                model="model",
                openai_api_type="azure",
                temperature=0,
                max_tokens=2000,
                api_version="api_version"
            )
toolkit = SQLDatabaseToolkit(db=db, llm=llm)
prompt = "Give me Plotly Data object of type Figure which gives students by city"

agent = create_sql_agent(
    llm=llm, 
    toolkit=toolkit, 
    verbose=True,
    agent_type=AgentType.ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION,
    agent_executor_kwargs = {"return_intermediate_steps": True}
)

response = agent.invoke({"input":prompt})
sql_query = ''
for (log, output) in response["intermediate_steps"]:
    if log.tool == 'sql_db_query':
        sql_query += log.tool_input

print(response['output'])


as for me SQL Agent is for SQL queries, not for Plotly Data`. If you want Plotly Data then write normal code for this.
